# Make graphviz from sklearn RandomForestClassifier (not from individual clf.estimators_)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphviz, random-forest, decision-tree

Python. Sklearn. `RandomForestClassifier`. After fitting `RandomForestClassifier`, does it produce some kind of single "best" "averaged" consensus tree that could be used to create a graphviz?

Yes, I looked at the documentation. No it doesn't say anything about it. No `RandomForestClassifier` doesn't have a `tree_` attribute. However, you can get the individual trees in the forest from `clf.estimators_` so I know I could make a graphviz from one of those. There is an [example of that here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118016/how-can-you-print-the-decision-tree-of-a-randomforestclassifier). I could even score all trees and find the tree with the highest score amongst the forest and choose that one... but that's not what I'm asking.

I want to make a graphviz from the "averaged" final random forest classifier result. Is this possible? Or, does the final classifier use the underlying trees to produce scores and predictions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `RandomForest` is an ensemble method that uses averaging to do prediction, i.e. all the fitted sub classifiers are used, *typically* (but not always) in a majority voting ensemble, to arrive at the final prediction. This is usually true for all ensemble methods. As `Vivek Kumar` points out in the comments, the prediction is not necessarily always a pure majority vote but can also be a weighted majority or indeed some other exotic form of combining the individual predictions (research on ensemble methods is ongoing although somewhat sidelined by deep learning).

There is no average tree that could be graphed, only the decision stumps that were trained from random sub samples of the whole dataset and the predictions that each of those produces. It's the predictions themselves that are averaged, not the trees / stumps.

---

Just for completeness, from the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest): (emphasis mine)

> Random forests or random decision forests[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest)[2] are an ensemble learning method for classification, regression and other tasks, that operate by constructing a multitude of decision trees at training time and outputting the class that is the **mode** of the classes (classification) or **mean** prediction (regression) of the individual trees.

**mode** being the most common value, in other words the majority prediction.

Comment: So the concept is, a random forest model has a bunch of children (decision trees). Those children can then vote. The mode (usually, but sometimes the mean) of child votes determines score or prediction output. Is that abstractly right?

Comment: I don't think of them as "_children_" of the "_parent_" because it leads to this notion of there being a parent tree. There is no parent, it's a collection of decision trees each trained on a random subset of the corpus. Think of them as neighbours rather than children. 

The majority vote (sometimes weighted majority) is used for classification, mean vote is for regression (predicting a numerical output like a house price or travel time).